# Mock static methods

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have a static method in a class. the method is not final. I keep getting a when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock' error. Below is my code.

```
mockStatic(HomefeedExperimentUtils.class);

when(HomefeedExperimentUtils.getGroupAndActivateExperiment(
    "link_stock_signal_filter_exp")).thenReturn(
    "treatment");
```

I've also tried:

```
HomefeedExperimentUtils mock = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(HomefeedExperimentUtils.class);

when(mock.getGroupAndActivateExperiment(
    "link_stock_signal_filter_exp")).thenReturn(
    "treatment");
```

Any help with be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't mock statics. Test public behavior, and if the statics are public, test them directly.

Comment: Do not use `static` methods in the first place. They make your code inflexible and hard to reuse (as your problem to use a mock instead shows). And no: there is no rule that utility classes *must* have static methods...

Answer (score 0):

Mockito is not able perform static mocking, use PowerMock to extend their capability and achieve that.

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki

Comment: But before you surrender to your bad design by using PowerMock remove the `static` key word from that method under test!